# Explicit solution to nonlinear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I'm trying to find an explicit solution $u(t)$ of
$$
\dot{u} = \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha t}-u},\quad u(0)=0
$$
where $\alpha>0$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ are given constants. I did not know how to solve it directly, so I tried to solve it numerically, but still I could not find a way to find an explicit solution.

Does anybody have idea to solve it. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you would need $\alpha > 8\beta$ for a solution to exists at all.

Answer (score 1):

Change variable to $y=\sqrt{\alpha t}-u$. This will give
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{du}{dt}-\sqrt{\alpha}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}.
$$
The equation becomes
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\beta}{y}-\sqrt{\alpha}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}.
$$
This equation can be solved by taking $y=C\sqrt{t}$ that gives
$$
\frac{C}{2}-\frac{\beta}{C}=\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{2}
$$ 
that determines $C$.

Answer (score 1):

With the change of variables
$u = v \sqrt{t}$
your ode becomes

$$\dot u = \dot v \sqrt{t} + \frac{v}{2\sqrt{t}} = \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{t}(\sqrt{\alpha} - v)}$$
hence
$$ \dot v = \frac{\beta}{t(\sqrt{\alpha} - v)}-  \frac{v}{2t} = \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{\beta}{(\sqrt{\alpha} - v)}-  v\right)$$
which is separable.